# react-native run-ios ends up with error 65 - cannot build

Tags: react-native

React-Native run-ios build error 65

I've tried many things.  I did a pod install in the ios folder.  I tried pod update.  I tried restarting VScode and xcode.  I tried restarting the computer.  I tried running another react-native project successfully.  I tried doing a gem instal cocoapods.  I tried commenting out components.  I don't know what else to try.

[image]

Simulator 11.1
Xcode 11.1
vscode 1.38.1

Comment: Are you add fonts you are used in the xcode project?

Comment: I didn't add any fonts.  how would I add the fonts to the xcode?

Comment: Can you share your package.json to be sure if I'm right firstly